# How can I recreate a python virtual environment with all installed packages offline?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a `python` virtual environment in which the following packages are installed:

```
ad3==2.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
cvxopt==1.1.9
Cython==0.29
decorator==4.3.0
Django==1.9.4
djangorestframework==3.6.4
lda==1.1.0
networkx==2.2
nltk==3.3
numpy==1.14.5
pbr==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pystruct==0.3.2
pytz==2018.7
scikit-learn==0.20.0
scipy==1.1.0
six==1.11.0
South==1.0.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Wand==0.4.5
```

The versions of the packages are very important and since the wheel files of some of them are not available to be able to install them offline, I am seeking a way so I can, for instance, pack up my virtual environment's installed packages as a solid package, to be able to setup the desired virtual environment whenever and wherever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try virtualenv-clone 0.5.1.......
https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv-clone/